# GitHub store files encrypted

Tags: git, security, encryption, github

due to the fact that all files on GitHub are stored within the U.S. and it is officially known that the government has the right to access and read such data (even from companies in Europe).

**I need to know if it is possible to store files encrypted?**

like some type of auto encryption and decryption when I push/pull the files.

Comment: ... or directed at your lawyer. Quite likely the US could just subpoena your encryption keys too.

Comment: The encypted files will essentially look like binary files (i.e. random junk) so all the nice Git compression measures that assume that file's will have common history will fail, leaving you with a large repo, even when packed. - It's been discussed a number of times and isn't simple.

Answer (score 3):

There's a solution [git-crypt](https://www.agwa.name/projects/git-crypt/) that I've come across before but never used personally.

However, as others have mentioned there are a number of side-effects that occur when using git encryption.

If you are concerned with data security, it would be better to run your own personal Git server (either on your own hardware or on a cloud provider that hosts outside of the US).

Comment: As of 2020, `git-crypt` is [not recommended for encrypting a whole repo](https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt/issues/214#issuecomment-711097877). It works okay for a few files.

Answer (score 1):

As you can store any type of file in Git, you could store encrypted files in Git. However, to get 'git diff' etc. to work, you will need to decrypt the files on-the-fly (and possibly modify the git sources to account for the necessity of this decryption).

If you feel up to it, adding this encryption/decryption capability might make a nice addition to Git -- I bet there are people out there who would be happy to use your enhancement.